# Using "this" in getters/setters in C#

Tags: c#, this, getter-setter

Short and sweet (hopefully), is there a specific reason *not* to use the `this` keyword when writing getters and setters in C#?  I know the typical format, and the one I've always used, is:

```
    public void SetDay(int _day) { day = _day; }
    public int GetDay()
    {
        return day;
    }
```

Recently though, I've been learning Java, and in several of the books I've been using I've seen it written instead like this:

```
    public void SetDay(int _day) { this.day = _day; }
    public int GetDay()
    {
        return this.day;
    }
```

So basically, is there a reason to avoid doing it the same way in C#?  Will it cause any problems or errors, or is it a valid approach and really just a matter of personal preference.  I'm wondering because, while I know the `this` in C# is understood, explicitly using the `this` keyword seems like it would aid in eliminating a bit extra ambiguity, which personally is always a good thing.

Thank you!

Comment: This is purely a matter of style (and thus opinion-based). Most people tend to use a prefix like `_day` or `m_day` for member variables, **not** for parameters/local vars.

Comment: Be consistent in your use. If you use it in most places (where it isn't necessary), use it in all places.

Comment: Also, why are you using getter/setter functions in C#, which has [***properties***](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx)?

Comment: Excellent point actually, it's been about a year since I've done anything in C#, and I had honestly forgotten about Properties completely.  This reminded me of them, and give me something to brush up on...Thanks!

Comment: The only reason to write `this` is when in your method you have local variable with same name as property or field.

Comment: @Atomosk not really the only reason, adding this also makes scope of a variable immediately clear.

Comment: Question edited to ensure understanding of the original intent, that being whether this is something to avoid for a specific reason (introducing bugs, causing conflicts, etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not much to it really. 
You can do it, and you can avoid it. I think it's quite obvious when you're in the getter/setter that you're talking about the object you're in, so I've never used it there.

Also, it seems like Resharper will suggest it's redundant, and gray it out.

If you find it to be of use for you (readability wise), by all means, use it. Otherwise, it'll save you five keystrokes (about a second?) every time you implement a getter by hand ... :)

Comment: No worries, glad it helped. Keep in mind that different languages also have different conventions. In C# for example one is to use `<` and not `<=` in for loops it seems, so it might be different for Java